# How to get useful BigQuery errors

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a job that I run with `jobs().insert()`

Currently I have the job failing with:

> 2014-11-11 11:19:15,937 - ERROR - bigquery - invalid: Could not convert value to string

Considering I have 500+ columns, I find this error message useless and pretty pathetic. What can I do to receive a proper and better error details from BigQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structured error return dictionary contains 3 elements, a "reason", a "location", and a "message". From the log line you include, it looks like only the message is logged.

Here's an example error return from a CSV import with data that doesn't match the target table schema:

```
"errors": [
   {
    "reason": "invalid",
    "location": "File: 0 / Line:2 / Field:1",
    "message": "Value cannot be converted to expected type."
   },
   ...
```

Similar errors are returned from JSON imports with data that doesn't match the target table schema.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that field!